# Implement a Third-Party Authentication in .NET 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, custom-authentication

I'm new to .net. I'm trying to make a login/Sign system in which You can login with my custom authentication.
Like when we see "Login with Google" or "Login with facebook".
Just Like that I can to make something like "Login with XYZ" and implement it's full functionality.
Can anyone help me in this, as I'm very new to programming so I don't know how to implement it.
Thank you

Comment: Is the Login with XYZ use any standard authentication protocol like OAuth2? Then it is possible. If it is a custom authentication you need to implement your own. You can find few authentication providers here - https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers

Comment: OAuth2 is basically just the authentication medium, right?
Then I don't think I would want my own custom authentication.
I just want that when I click on "Login with xyz" I'm redirected to xyz's login page and if the credentials are right for xyz, then I'm logged in to the app.

Comment: Hi@kamran bajwa, Do you just wanna use multi multi authentication in asp.net core? For example, you can  choose to use google, facebook or other kind account to log in?

Comment: @kamranbajwa To support your scenario you need some standard authentication mechanism like OAuth 2. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: @XinranShen Yes like this but custom Like "Login with xyz"

Comment: @Anuraj how can I implement this using oauth?